# Can I do exponential binary search, or open-interval git bisect?

Tags: git, version-control

## Situation

`git bisect` is great to locate the commit that introduced a bug. You just need to know a good commit where the bug is not present, a (newer) bad commit where it is present, and a method to test whether the bug is present in any given commit. Then `git bisect` guides you through a binary search.

## Question

I'm interested in the situation where I *don't* know a good commit. I'm assuming that there is one in the past, but I just don't remember it. Finding it out manually is a huge manual labour that I want to avoid.

*Can I run `git bisect` in a way such that I don't need to specify a good commit?* Can it find a good commit for me?

I'm surprised this problem isn't well-known. I run into it every month.

## A barely usable approach

One approach might be taking the first commit of the repository and marking that as good. But this has a number of problems.

- [There may not be a single first commit.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188914/how-to-show-first-commit-by-git-log) Sometimes it's nontrivial to choose.
- The method of testing for the bug will probably not apply for the first commit, and for many early commits to follow. Simply because the test will not compile, run, or be compatible with the code. I could `git bisect skip` it, but [it's not so clear which commit will be picked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36497937/how-does-git-bisect-skip-choose-the-next-commit-to-try).
- The repository might be huge. Like, [hundreds of thousands of commits](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/). If I don't have a way to efficiently skip many unusable commits, there is no way to go through all of it.

## Proposal: Exponential search

The standard solution to such a problem is [exponential search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search). The good commit is located by going to `HEAD~1`, then `HEAD~2`, `HEAD~4`, `HEAD~8` and so on until a good commit is encountered. This also works in logarithmic time and is much better than going backwards through all the history, because we start with commits to which our testing method will probably apply well.

*Is exponential search implemented for `git bisect`*? Are there helper scripts that do it? How do you solve this problem?

Comment: This very feature was discussed 8 years ago on the git mailing list: https://public-inbox.org/git/20120318212957.GS1219@chaosreigns.com/